# How to perform realtime video stitching using OpenCv, I am using cv2.Stitcher_create() method on each frame

Tags: python, opencv

"I am attempting to develop a real-time video stitcher with a broader angle of view. My goal is to achieve a panoramic effect in my stitched videos rather than simply connecting the image frames horizontally. I aim to utilize overlapping areas in each camera frame to seamlessly stitch them together.

While the following code initially execute for a few second and shows the stitched live video in a very jittering way but it eventually crashes with the following error

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) /io/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/compat_ptsetreg.cpp:125: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !err.empty() in function 'update'
```

Could someone please assist me in improving it or provide guidance on how to address this issue?"

```
import cv2

class StitcherWithCache:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stitcher = cv2.Stitcher_create()
        self.cache = {}

    def stitch_frames(self, frame1, frame2):
        frames_key = (tuple(frame1.flatten()), tuple(frame2.flatten()))

        if frames_key in self.cache:
            result, _ = self.cache[frames_key]
            return result

        status, result = self.stitcher.stitch([frame1, frame2])


        if status:
            pass
        else:
            self.cache[frames_key] = (result.copy(), status)

        return result

# Initialize video captures for both cameras (replace with your video sources)
camera1 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
camera2 = cv2.VideoCapture(4)

# Initialize Stitcher with cache
stitcher_with_cache = StitcherWithCache()

# Capture initial frames for pre-populating the cache
ret1, frame1 = camera1.read()
ret2, frame2 = camera2.read()

if ret1 and ret2:
    # Resize frames if necessary
    frame1 = cv2.resize(frame1, (0, 0), fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
    frame2 = cv2.resize(frame2, (0, 0), fx=0.4, fy=0.4)

    # Perform stitching without caching for the initial frames
    stitched_result = stitcher_with_cache.stitch_frames(frame1, frame2)

    if stitched_result is not None:
        print('Your Panorama is ready!!!')

        # Display stitched result
        cv2.imshow('Stitched Result', stitched_result)

while True:
    # Capture frames from the video streams
    ret1, frame1 = camera1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = camera2.read()

    # time.sleep(0.5)

    # Check if frames are captured successfully
    if ret1 and ret2:
        # Resize frames if necessary
        frame1 = cv2.resize(frame1, (0, 0), fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
        frame2 = cv2.resize(frame2, (0, 0), fx=0.4, fy=0.4)

        # Display original frames
        # cv2.imshow('Frame 1', frame1)
        # cv2.imshow('Frame 2', frame2)

        # Perform stitching with caching
        stitched_result = stitcher_with_cache.stitch_frames(frame1, frame2)

        if stitched_result is not None:
            print('Your Panorama is ready!!!')

            # Display stitched result
            cv2.imshow('Stitched Result', stitched_result)

    # Break the loop if 'Esc' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

# Release the video captures
camera1.release()
camera2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expecting code that will stitch video in real time without getting crashed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "it eventually crashes" ... then it might be a good idea to include the complete error message with backtrace.

Comment: @DanMašek I have edited my query and also paste the error. But I feel there might be a better way to do "real time video stitching". So my wish is to know how people are doing realtime video stitching.